# AS3 Print Job Not Working With Chrome

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome

So I have run into a strange problem with Chrome and I haven't been able to find any posts online speaking to a similar issue. I have a script in an AS3 app that takes a screenshot as bitmap data and sends it to the printer with the PrintJob object. It works fine from within flash, locally on my desktop, and in every browser but Chrome.

When I print with Chrome the bitmap image just displays as a grey box instead of the actual image itself. If i add the bitmap to the stage and view it from Chrome I can see that the bitmap actually contains image data other than a 50% grey fill but as soon as it is sent to PrintJob Chrome seems to strip it of this data.

This is the code I am using:

```
function printImage(clip:Sprite){
      var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
      printJob.start();                 
      printJob.addPage(clip);           
      printJob.send();
};

var clip:Sprite = new Sprite();
clip.addChild(bitmap);
printImage(clip);
```

Also it is worth noting that when I set the PrintJobOptions.printAsBitmap to be true the grey box begins appearing in all instances not just Chrome

Thanks so much for any help!!

Comment: it was already answered on SO, add the clip to stage before sending to print, then after you can remove it from stage again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113403/flash-printing-chrome-omits-sprites-when-printing/12317116#12317116

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue with Chrome that any DisplayObject that is being assigned for print needs to be on the stage.

Simply add it to the stage and remove it afterward and you should be go.

However, I typically like to set up a holding container buried behind everything to prevent the blink of adding/removing the child.

Comment: I'm just putting the above answer since this was the first result from Google and the original post that answered was posted as a comment in this thread and also has a specific implementation.